# Significance of the word 'general' in CMakeCache.txt?

Tags: cmake

I encountered following statement in one of the CMakeCache.txt. 
`SomelibraryName_LIB_DEPENDS:STATIC=general;gcc_s;general;pthread;general;rt;general;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind.so;general;dl;general;uuid;general;`

why general is required here? Also even if it is not mentioned here *SomelibraryName* is also depends on other libraries such as *libc,libstdc++* and *libm*. Does general refer to these extra libraries?

Comment: `*_LIB_DEPENDS` is **internal** CMake variable, which probably [will be removed](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16364) in the future. Are you really want to know its meaning?

Comment: When I used 'ldd SomelibraryName.so' I could see these libraries. I am confused about the word general. Because it is repetitive and there is no general.so on which somelibraryName.so depends.

Comment: Hmm, as far as I understand, `*_LIB_DEPENDS` variable is intended for target's *exporting*, so content of this variable shouldn't be used for compilation/linking *directly*. Could you provide an example (`CMakeLists.txt` file), with which `ldd` outputs "general"?

Comment: `ldd` do not output "general" but it output other names in the list which are `libpthread.so, librt.so, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunwind.so, libdl.so, libuuid.so`.

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: I know nearly nothing about CMake internals.

My educated guess is it's the same "general" as in [`target_link_libraries(<target> ... <item>...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/target_link_libraries.html) docs:

> A debug, optimized, or general keyword immediately followed by another `<item>`. The item following such a keyword will be used only for the corresponding build configuration. The **debug** keyword corresponds to the Debug configuration (...). The **optimized** keyword corresponds to all other configurations. The **general** keyword corresponds to all configurations, and is purely optional.

I.e. "general" is an attribute of library following it and not some build artifact.
In example below different versions of `some_lib` will be linked depending on build type, but the same versions of `another_lib1` and `another_lib2` will be linked disregarding build type.

```
target_link_libraries(my_target
    debug some_lib_DEBUG_VER
    optimized some_lib
    general another_lib1
    another_lib2
)
```